# Radio advert project

Tags: mix, levels, radio, broadcast-standards

I have a radio project due in a week and a half's time. I have recorded the dialogue at 44.1, 32 bit. I would just like to know what the radio broadcast level is?

Comment: Unfortunately it varies depending on what company and in which country, both of which you haven't specified, you're delivering to. EBU R128 is the new and "an actual" standard they're trying to pass through though.

Comment: sorry south africa it is a college project 

Answer (score 1):

Most radio spots are done at 48K sampling rate, audio post in general really.  Here in the US there aren't any broadcast level specs, most people just set their output limiters at -1 or 2.  From there you just mix with your monitors at the correct level and make a nice sounding mix.  The stations themselves handle the final compression before the signal is broadcast.

Answer (score 0):

contact the radio station and ask. Look on their website etc. Look for eg. audio specification